# What Address should I give in From field in SendEmail using c#

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I caught into big problem since am new to SMTP Email Server.

I have installed smtp server in my web server and configured the required details. My emails are now sending but in spam
I have implemented SendMail code using c# in my webapplication and I have one clarification on that.

```
    string mailFrom = "Newsletter@my-domain.com";
        string message = string.Empty;  

        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage email = new MailMessage(mailFrom, EmailAddress);
        email.Subject = "Mail from my-domain.com";
        email.Body = message;
        email.IsBodyHtml = true;
        email.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient();
        System.Net.NetworkCredential basicAuthenticationInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        mailClient.Host = "my-mail-server-domain.com";
        mailClient.Port = 25;
        mailClient.EnableSsl = false;
        mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        mailClient.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo;
        try
        {
            mailClient.Send(email);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("File");
            logger.Error(ex.ToString());
        }
```

What value should I give for mailFrom. Is valid email is required for From address? Does it cause sending mail as spam? I don't have emailid in the name of newsletter@my-domain.com. What shall I do for that?

Please anyone clarify on this.

Answer (score 0):

It is the responsibility of the mail server the validation of the address, all could be good or bad for c#. I think your focus is wrong.

Comment: Then what could be the reason for sending mail to spam?

Comment: Try using real sender address

Answer (score 0):

The from should be a valid email address. That is the email from where an email is sent. The network credentials that you specify must match with the from address. Once you provide a valid email address, the emails will not go to spam folder hopefully.

Comment: In my case, what would be the valid email address? Does it require to create email account? Where I can create it?